# Express app with Playwright - Google Cloud Run - local deploy failed

Tags: node.js, docker, gcloud, playwright

I keep getting an error in output 'Cloud run: Run/Debug locally detailed':

```
    Starting deploy...
    Configuring \"\" for node.js debugging
    \"....-container\" requires debugging support image \"nodejs\"
    Configuring installation of debugging support files
     - Warning: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[4].name: duplicate name "K_CONFIGURATION"
     - Warning: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[5].name: duplicate name "K_REVISION"
     - Warning: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[6].name: duplicate name "K_SERVICE"
```

Have changed ENV variable names couple of times, no luck.
Have changed Node version.
Have installed each 'apt-get' separately, to check if they gave errors.

This is my current launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally",
            "type": "cloudcode.cloudrun",
            "request": "launch",
            "build": {
                "docker": {
                    "path": "Dockerfile"
                }
            },
            "image": "kservicenamename22",
            "service": {
                "name": "kservicenamename22",
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "env": [
                    {
                        "name": "K_SERVICE",
                        "value": "kservicenamename22"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "K_REVISION",
                        "value": "kservicenamename22.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "K_CONFIGURATION",
                        "value": "kservicenamename22"
                    }
                ],
                "resources": {
                    "limits": {
                        "cpu": 2,
                        "memory": "2048Mi"
                    }
                }
            },
            "target": {
                "minikube": {}
            },
            "watch": true
        }
    ]
}
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst \
ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget && \
wget https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.1/dumb-init_1.2.1_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i dumb-init_*.deb && rm -f dumb-init_*.deb && \
apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
### removed 'ttf-freefont' - gave error while downloading. 

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
ENV PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD = 1 
RUN npm install
RUN npx playwright install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

Gcloud versions:

```
Google Cloud SDK 435.0.1
alpha 2023.06.14
beta 2023.06.14
bq 2.0.93
core 2023.06.14
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin 0.5.3
gsutil 5.24
kubectl 1.25.9
minikube 1.30.1
skaffold 2.4.1
```

package.json (removed some lines):

```
{
  "name": "myname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
     "start": "nodemon app"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
   },
  
   "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "got": "^13.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "playwright-chromium": "^1.35.0"
  }
}
```

Hope someone has some pointers on how to investigate and fix this. Have a couple of projects which all use the same setup and they all are broken now.

Comment: Are you using Google Cloud Secret Manager? You may need to add a specific version for each secret variable (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets#access-secrets)